# I changed my MAMP httpd.conf, and now the Apache server won't start

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp

I am setting up MAMP on Mac M1 Big Sur.

In MAMP's `httpd.conf` I edited `DocumentRoot` to point to a different folder than the default (`Users/MyName/Sites`), and I uncommented the line `Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. I also ran `mysql upgrade` and got a positive result.

MAMP now will not run. MAMP no longer displays individual status for Apache and MySQL but the server status indicator is yellow. I did the killall on httpd processes and no running instances were found, so I think Apache is not running.

When I return to the MAMP start up screen, the Document Root doesn't say `Users/MyName/Sites` as expected. It says `/Pradde/Programme/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/empty.crt` instead.

I haven't uncommented any lines related to SSL. I'm running on port 80 to match the way my VirtualHosts are set up.

How can I get this working? Do I have to use the default file location?

Comment: Hey David. Wondering if you got this working. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Jammy: I did get it working. Restarting the whole machine seemed to help. MAMP still shows that strange looking Document Root when you open the Preferences, then changes to the Document Root I put in, so I guess that is some kind of virtual Document Root.
One other issue I had is that I had Virtual Hosts in my Virtual Hosts file that I had deleted, that will cause this error. I located the logs for MAMP and was able to find the error that way.

Comment: Thanks David! I was able to get rid of the issue by uninstalling/reinstalling MAMP and rebooting my machine. Was driving me crazy!